# Select different jquery-ui tabs based on code behind state

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, .net-4.0

I am making a webapp, using ASP.NET, C#, and jQuery with 4 tabs, and a form on the third tab for the user to fill out.  However, whenever the user submits the form data, it goes back to the first tab, and I want it to go to either the second tab, or stay on the third tab, depending on what the user put into the form.  So far though, the only way I can get this to work is to use `Response.redirect()` to reload the page with the proper anchor tag (#tab-2 or #tab-3), which will have the page display the proper tag.  However, doing this will loose all of the data submitted in the form, so I would also need to put all of the form data in the query string, which seems like a terrible idea.

Ideally what I would like to do is have the page load to the proper tab.

So I currently have this function which gets called after the user clicks a button (I think this gets called as the server is loading the page):

```
public virtual void editClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Get the data
    string primaryUser = Request.Form.Get (CompPrimUser.UniqueID);
    string computerName = Request.Form.Get (compCompName.UniqueID);

    // Data verification
    if (computerName == "") {
        // Bad data, reload third tab with user's entered data
        // and inform them they need to fix it.
        compeditId.Value = POSTED;
        return;
    }

    // Store the Data, display second tab
}
```

compeditId is a hidden field, which on the `Page_Load()` call for that page, will fill the form at properly based on the posted data rather than an empty field (or from the mysql database).

I thought about calling `Server.Transfer()` as a way of loading the page with the proper anchor tag, but it only uses the .aspx file, ignoring any of the remaining query string.

Finally, I'm using the clip directly from the jquery website for turning the query string into the proper tab, namely:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("a, intput:submit", ".toplevelnav").button();
        $("a", ".toplevelnav").click(function () { return true; });
    });
    $(function () { $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" }); });
    $(function() { $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); });
</script>
```

And have the actual tabs listed in html:

```
<div id="tabs" style=" font-size:14px;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Clients Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Client Detail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Computers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Settings</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <cab:ClientList ID="clientList" runat="server" />
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <cab:ClientDetail ID="clientDetail" runat="server" />
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        <cab:Computers ID="computers" runat="server" />    
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-4">

    </div>

</div>
```

So does anyone have any ideas on how I can have the server send a different tab selected by default than the one based on the query string?  Or at least have the server change the query string without loosing the posted data in a form?

Thank you.

Edit:  I also tried using the html form's action attribute tag to tell it to submit to an aspx file with the `#tab-3` anchor.  However, the server ignores this.  Also, the problem with this is we don't know if we want the second or third tab until the data is sent to the server.

Comment: Why not just do an AJAX submit instead?

Comment: Why don't you put `#tab-2` or `#tab-3` in your form's `action` attribute?

Comment: @Manthletics, because I hadn't heard of it before, I'm looking into it now, hopefully it will work...

Comment: @Frederic, I tried, and it doesn't work.  The server seems to ignore the action attribute.

Comment: You could create a hidden control on the page such as a HtmlHiddenInput (I think thats the class name). Bind a jQuery event to clicking on the tabs to set the hidden control's value to the ID of the tab. Your hidden input would have then have the tab's ID. Then, you could set the active tab based on the hidden input's value, just as @FrédéricHamidi has suggested

Comment: @Leif, what I meant was that you can determine the next tab to activate *from the client side* before submitting the form. Since your default behavior is to switch to the second tab on postback, put `#tab-2` in your form's `action` server-side. Then, client-side, if the `compCompName` input element is empty on submit, update your form's action to `#tab-3` and let the event proceed with its default behavior.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the server ignores the server ignores the action field.  If we added the anchor there, it ignores it.  If we set it to an entirely different page, it ignores it, and submits it to the same page.  So even if we always wanted it to go to tab 2, it still wouldn't work.  (Well, usually it would, but the server strips it out before sending it the client).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After submitting form, you can use `$("#tabs").tabs("select",2)` to select the third tab.

If you're using jQuery UI 1.9+, you must use the `active` property:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ active:2 });
```

Comment: The OP will still need to maintain some place holder for which tab index or ID should be the active tab.

Comment: @Splash-X of course. he can set tab index depending on what the user filled in.

Comment: Yes, running that line of jquery will select the proper tab.  However, there doesn't seem to be any way to run that line from within the C# code (`editClicked()` function).

Comment: well, one way is to echo a small portion of javascript code. something like `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){ $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "select" , 2); });</script>` in editClicked function

Comment: This line more or less did it thank you.  A hidden field was placed in a form, and we put the desired tab in the hidden field.  Then we used the DOM to look at the value, and go to it.

Answer (score 2):

Since your server apparently strips the fragments from the form's `action` attribute, you have to consider the selected tab as state that should be maintained on the server and transmitted to the client.

Server-side, you can keep track of the tab to select:

```
private int _tabToSelect = 0;  // Default to first tab.

public virtual void editClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the data.
    string primaryUser = Request.Form.Get(CompPrimUser.UniqueID);
    string computerName = Request.Form.Get(compCompName.UniqueID);

    // Data verification.
    if (computerName == "") {
        // Bad data, reload third tab with user's entered data
        // and inform them they need to fix it.
        _tabToSelect = 2;
        compeditId.Value = POSTED;
        return;
    }

    // Display second tab.
    _tabToSelect = 1;

    // Store the data...
}
```

Then, to relay that information to the client, you can [register a script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx):

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(ThisClass),
        "TabToSelect", String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "var _Page_tabToSelect = {0};", _tabToSelect), true);
}
```

From there, you only have to select the proper tab client-side:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        selected: _Page_tabToSelect
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this a few different ways, as previous answers show, you could use the session, query string, or use the model (query string, just less code) to pass the value.

Personally I would do something like this.

You need a separate controller action for each form tab.
For example, you would have ActionResult RenderWhateverTab1 (WhateverModel model).

The JQ Tabs supports using a RenderAction or RenderPartial as content for a link.

Then you can pass back the model on a back click via actionlink.

@Html.RenderAction("RenderWhateverTab1", "WhateverController", model);

If the back link needs to be on a different (summary style) page, then you can set a BackLinkUrl property on the model for the summary page, and in each of your tab controller calls set the BackLinkUrl to @Url.Action(("RenderWhateverTab1", "WhateverController", model);

This allows each tab to be called with all the data it needs (sticky forms), and the render for the tab state can be set as a previous url on each individual tab call.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
if (allIsGood)
{
    do this and that
}
else
{
    //keep user on 3rd tab (note: change CurrClass to your codebehind class name)
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(CurrClass),
    "TabToSelect", "$('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 2 })", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `class` in `div` tag you can directly activate the tab by using this:

```
$("#tab_1").addClass("active");
```